# Credential is null for the action - error is found while running a mapreduce job in oozie

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie

When I try to run the map-reduce job in oozie 4.0.1 using hadoop 2.2.0. I get the following error

```
hadoopuser@hadoopmaster:/usr/lib/oozie-4.0.1/distro/target/oozie-4.0.1-distro/oozie-4.0.1$ oozie job -oozie http://hadoopmaster:11000/oozie -log 0000001-141029094805376-oozie-hado-W
2014-10-29 09:56:34,680  INFO ActionStartXCommand:539 - USER[hadoopuser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] JOB[0000001-141029094805376-oozie-hado-W] ACTION[0000001-141029094805376-oozie-hado-W@:start:] Start action [0000001-141029094805376-oozie-hado-W@:start:] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2014-10-29 09:56:34,681  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[hadoopuser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] JOB[0000001-141029094805376-oozie-hado-W] ACTION[0000001-141029094805376-oozie-hado-W@:start:] [***0000001-141029094805376-oozie-hado-W@:start:***]Action status=DONE
2014-10-29 09:56:34,681  WARN ActionStartXCommand:542 - USER[hadoopuser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] JOB[0000001-141029094805376-oozie-hado-W] ACTION[0000001-141029094805376-oozie-hado-W@:start:] [***0000001-141029094805376-oozie-hado-W@:start:***]Action updated in DB!
2014-10-29 09:56:34,781  INFO ActionStartXCommand:539 - USER[hadoopuser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] JOB[0000001-141029094805376-oozie-hado-W] ACTION[0000001-141029094805376-oozie-hado-W@mr-node] Start action [0000001-141029094805376-oozie-hado-W@mr-node] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2014-10-29 09:56:34,932  WARN MapReduceActionExecutor:542 - USER[hadoopuser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] JOB[0000001-141029094805376-oozie-hado-W] ACTION[0000001-141029094805376-oozie-hado-W@mr-node] credentials is null for the action
```

My workflow.xml is as given below

```
  <workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2" name="map-reduce-wf">
    <start to="mr-node"/>
    <action name="mr-node">
        <map-reduce>
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>

            <configuration>

        <property>
            <name>mapred.reducer.new-api</name>
            <value>true</value>
          </property>
          <property>
            <name>mapred.mapper.new-api</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.mapper.class</name>
                    <value>org.apache.oozie.example.SampleMapper</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.reducer.class</name>
                    <value>org.apache.oozie.example.SampleReducer</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.map.tasks</name>
                    <value>1</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
                    <value>/user/hadoopuser/examples/input-data/text</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.output.dir</name>
                    <value>/user/hadoopuser/examples/output-data/${outputDir}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
        </map-reduce>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Map/Reduce failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

When I access the oozie.log for that job id I find Authentication token expired warnings and then 'credential is null for the action' error.

Please help me. I am stuck in this error since a long time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Its just a WARN, isn't it? Does the oozie job finishes?

Comment: No oozie job stuck in Running mode only.